# Can NETLINK_ROUTE channel be used to send messages from kernel module to a user-space program?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, netlink

I have written a user-space program that polls for the status of the available Ethernet interfaces for their operational status using `netlink` sockets with `NETLINK_ROUTE` protocol.
But now I want to write a kernel module which uses the NETLINK_ROUTE channel to send customized notification message to this user-space program.
After reading the man page for `netlink` and `rtnetlink` I cannot conclude if it is doable. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

NETLINK_ROUTE is not a protocol - it's one of the netlink families. From manpage:

> netlink_family selects the kernel module or netlink group to
>   communicate with.

Netlink was initially developed for fast and easy messaging about routing info and that's why NETLINK_ROUTE is first family and have own manpages, manuals, etc. But later other families were added to send other than routing info, e.g. NETLINK_SELINUX and NETLINK_FIREWALL.

After some time developers saw that there are way too many specific families. If somebody wants to use that fancy netlink protocol he needs to declare another family and make it even worse. So they added last family - NETLINK_GENERIC that works like multiplexer. There is a great manual about generic netlink on lwn - http://lwn.net/Articles/208755/. If you want working examples you can look at my code (https://github.com/dzeban/keymon)

So, if your notifications related to any specific netlink family like NETLINK_ROUTE - then use it. But if you want to just send your very own and custom info - use generic netlink.

Comment: I want to use the `NETLINK_ROUTE` family only. But what i observed that you cannot create a socket using `netlink_kernel_create` with `NETLINK_ROUTE` as it is already owned by the kernel. So now i need to send the custom message using this already created socket. How do i send a dummy message? Any idea?